# Javascript Regex Resources

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to decode this regex statement in javascript, im new to regex and cant find many good resources.

I think the below means find any characters between two single quotes is that correct and what does each character mean in this statement?

From what i understand so far is the first / and last / tell js to look for a pattern.

Can anyone break this regex down into pieces?

```
    mystring = mystring.match(/'([^']+)'/)[0];
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info/ http://regex101.com/

Comment: Look at the return type for [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). It returns an array or null.

Comment: Give a look at the top-right panel in this site: _https://regex101.com/r/vC6eW1/1_

Comment: There's no good resources for regex.. It's only practice..

Comment: I wrote the following book, free and it might be of help.   https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/regularexpressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, this finds the word or a character that is in between the   single quotes. you can view the below code for example.

```
var mystring ="This is 'some' random 'test' with string";
mystring = mystring.match(/'([^']+)'/)[0];
alert(mystring); // This alerts 'some'
```

Explanation:

```
/'([^']+)'/
```

' matches the character ' literally

```
1st Capturing group ([^']+)

[^']+ match a single character not present in the list below
```

Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

' the literal character '

' matches the character ' literally